# jQuery - Getting .animate and .html to play nicely

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer-8

I'm trying not to nest these statements:

```
$('#capePowerpoint').animate({"right": "+=498px"}, 1000);
$('#capePowerPointContainer').html(capTabArray[capTabCounter][capabilitiesCounter]);
$('#capePowerpoint').animate({"right": "-=996px"}, 0);
$('#capePowerpoint').animate({"right": "+=498px"}, 1000);
```

If I comment out the .html line or the .animate lines they work correctly but when I try to combine them like this they just remove all the content from the div. Instead of scrolling the div off screen replacing it and then scrolling it back on from the opposite side.

Comment: Hi! I answered but seriously, if you need animation and like beautiful code, have a look at TweenLite : http://www.greensock.com/v12/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare callback methods in the `animate` calls!

```
$('#capePowerpoint').animate({"right": "+=498px"}, {duration:1000,complete:function(){
    $('#capePowerPointContainer').html(capTabArray[capTabCounter][capabilitiesCounter]);
    $('#capePowerpoint').animate({"right": "-=996px"}, {duration:0,complete:function(){
        $('#capePowerpoint').animate({"right": "+=498px"}, 1000);
    });
});
```

See more: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

If you're too much into jQuery `animate` method, like me (I hate it) see GreenSock's TweenLite library:

http://www.greensock.com/v12/

EDIT : You should save the elements instead of querying all over the place

```
var cape = $('#capePowerpoint'), container = $('#capePowerPointContainer');
cape.animate({"right": "+=498px"}, {duration:1000,complete:function(){
    container.html(capTabArray[capTabCounter][capabilitiesCounter]);
    cape.animate({"right": "-=996px"}, {duration:0,complete:function(){
        cape.animate({"right": "+=498px"}, 1000);
    });
});
```

Comment: I think the last animate statement even needs to be called in the callback for the second to last animate statement. Would that make sense? Or does it just add it to its queue and does the same thing?

Comment: Haha true, I like your EDIT. But technically, you don't have to store `cape` - you could reference `$(this)` inside of the main animation, couldn't you? So you could store `$(this)` inside, to prevent the 2 queries. Just a thought

Comment: I'm trying the above examples and I'm getting an error is complaining about the complete. With out it the second half doesn't run until I preform the function again.